# How to prove $((P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow P) \Rightarrow P$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Task: prove the Pierce's law by the natural deduction or by the system LK:

$\vdash ((P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow P) \Rightarrow P ?$
$((P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow P) \vdash P ?$
$¬P, ((P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow P) \vdash ?$

I tried to find proof:

$\vdash P \Rightarrow P !$
$P \vdash P !$
$P, (P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow P \vdash P !$
$P \vdash ((P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow P) \Rightarrow P !$

and

$(P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow P \vdash (P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow P$
$(P \Rightarrow Q), (P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow P \vdash P !$
$(P \Rightarrow Q) \vdash ((P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow P) \Rightarrow P !$

But there are formulas on the left.

Note: only implication and negation should be used.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Note that "prove" is not the same as "proof".

Comment: https://www.umsu.de/trees/

Comment: You can use truth table to show this logic too, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Natural Deduct proof in Gentzen's style:

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{(P\to Q)\to P\vdash (P\to Q)\to P}{\small\sf Ass}}{(P\to Q)\to P, (P\to Q)\vdash P}{\small{\to}\sf E}~~\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{P,\neg Q\vdash P}{\small\sf Ass}~~\dfrac{}{\neg P,\neg Q\vdash\neg P}{\small\sf Ass}}{P,\neg P\vdash Q}{\small\sf RAA}}{\neg P\vdash P\to Q}{\small\sf{\to}I}}{(P\to Q)\to P, \neg P\vdash P}{\small\sf Cut}~~\dfrac{}{\neg P\vdash \neg P}{\small\sf Ass}}{(P\to Q)\to P\vdash P}{\small\sf RAA}}{\vdash ((P\to Q)\to P)\to P}{\small\sf{\to}I}$$

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the details of the proof system you're using, it's impossible to give a full answer ("the propositional calculus" can refer to many different proof systems - they all prove the same tautologies, but the details are different). But here's an outline of a proof, which it should be straightforward to translate into your favorite proof system.

Assume $(P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow P$.

By the law of excluded middle, $P\lor \lnot P$. We'll prove $P$ by cases.

*Case 1:* $P$. We're done.

*Case 2:* $\lnot P$. Assume $P$. By explosion, $Q$. So $P\rightarrow Q$. By our assumption and modus ponens, $P$.

Having assumed $(P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow P$ and proven $P$, we have $((P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow P)\rightarrow P$.

---

As requested by the OP, I'll translate the above argument into the LK system as presented on [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus), using only the rules for $\rightarrow$ and $\lnot$ (together with the structural rules and cut).

1. $P\vdash P$ (I)
2. $\vdash \lnot P,P$ (1,$\lnot$R)
3. $\vdash P,\lnot P$ (2, PR)
4. $P\vdash Q,P$ (1, WR)
5. $P\vdash P,Q$ (4, PR)
6. $P,\lnot P\vdash Q$ (5, $\lnot$L)
7. $\lnot P,P\vdash Q$ (6, PL)
8. $\lnot P\vdash (P\rightarrow Q)$ (7, $\rightarrow$R).
9. $\vdash P,(P\rightarrow Q)$ (3,8,Cut)
10. $\vdash (P\rightarrow Q),P$ (9,PR)
11. $(P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow P \vdash P,P$ (10,1,$\rightarrow$L)
12. $(P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow P \vdash P$ (11,CR)
13. $\vdash ((P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow P)\rightarrow P$ (12,$\rightarrow$R)

This is really the same proof strategy as the informal proof above, though the LK system does everything it can to obscure the idea of the proof... I'll try to spell it out.

We start in lines 1-2 by asserting the law of excluded middle. Lines 3-8 argue via explosion (line 6) that $(P\rightarrow Q)$ follows from $\lnot P$. We unify these in line 9, concluding that either $P$ is true or $(P\rightarrow Q)$ is true (this corresponds to the reasoning by cases). Now we apply the especially obscure $\rightarrow$L rule, which says that if we further assume $(P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow P$ (putting it on the left hand side of the turnstile), then we can apply modus ponens to $(P\rightarrow Q)$ to get $P$ in the second case. Contraction in line 12 observes that in either case we get $P$. Thus, assuming $(P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow P$ gives $P$, and we have proven the implication in line 13.

Comment: I changed the question. You should use only implication and negation. You should not introduce new operations (disjunction, conjunction ...).

Comment: @user45001 ...and this is why it's important to clearly specify the proof system you're using! Even now, "only implication and negation should be used" is not nearly enough. You need to tell us what constitutes a proof, i.e. what proof rules / axioms you have at your disposal.

Comment: @user45001 Also, I still think it should be straightforward to translate my informal proof into your system. I only introduced disjunction to express the law of excluded middle. Your system has the law of excluded middle built into it somehow, and you should be able to figure out how to incorporate my use of excluded middle and reasoning by cases into your system.

Comment: sequent calculus: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus)

Comment: @user45001 Indeed... The page you link to describes two *different* systems of sequent calculus (in the sections "Proving logical formulas" and "The system LK") with *different rules*, as well as describing several variant systems, and all of these include logical connectives other than $\rightarrow$ and $\lnot$.

Comment: the system LK..

Comment: @user45001 Ok, thanks for clarifying. I've added a proof in LK, using only $\lnot$ and $\rightarrow$, to my answer.

Comment: ""the propositional calculus" can refer to many different proof systems - they all prove the same tautologies" There exist propositional calculi with 26 propositional variable symbols such as many formulated by Jan Lukasiewicz.  Layman Allen's in WFF 'N Proof has 4 propositional variable symbols.  Then there exist authors who allow for a countable number of propositional variable symbols.  A 6 variable tautology can't proved in a system with only 4 propositional variables. Thus, not all propositional calculi prove the same tautologies.  Also... (1/2)

Comment: there's the whole matter of whether or not a propositional calculus with a conditional symbol only, and a symbol for falsity, can prove tautologies from propositional calculi with disjunction and negation only.  And some other mismatches between the connectives of the calculi.  Intutionists would probably tell us that one propositional calculi A can't prove the tautologies of B, when A and B do not have the same connectives.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Sure, there are many different propositional logics too, and that makes the point I was making even more strongly. Usually when people write *the* propositional calculus, they're referring to a system which is sound and complete for classical propositional logic with the standard connectives, and by definition any two such systems prove the same tautologies. But your point is well-taken.

Comment: @alex-kruckman Thank you! I have decided that using natural deduction in the Gentzen's style is more suitable for my needs.

Comment: Why am I not surprised...

Answer (score 1):

One can use truth tables to show the claim. $((P \implies Q) \implies P) \implies P$.
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
P & Q & (P \implies Q) & ((P \implies Q) \implies P) & ((P \implies Q) \implies P) \implies P \\ \hline
T & T & T & T & T \\ \hline
T & F & F & T & T \\ \hline
F & T & T & F & T \\ \hline
F & F & T & F & T \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
Hence, the claim holds.

Comment: You're right. But the task is to prove this proposition using only the propositional calculus.

Comment: @user45001 Truth tables are a perfectly reasonable propositional calculus. So, before the question was edited to specify a sequent calculus, this answer was correct.

Answer (score 1):

- Let's admit these principles infered from the truth table of the $\rightarrow$ operator.

> (1) if the antecent of a conditional is false, the whole conditional
>   is true
>
> (2) if the antecedent is true while the consequent is false, then the
>   whole conditional is false.

- Now, suppose that $P$ is false.

In that case $( P{\rightarrow}Q)$ is true, because its antecedent is false ( Principle (1) above ) .

So $ ( ( P {\rightarrow}Q) {\rightarrow} P)$ must be false, since its antecedent is true and its consequent false ( Principle (2) above).

- So the negation of $P$  ( i.e. our hypothesis) implies the negation of the proposition $ ( ( P {\rightarrow}Q) {\rightarrow} P)$.
- By contraposition, it means that the conditional you want to prove is true.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Equivalently, prove $(P \land \neg Q) \lor P \implies P$. Consider the 2 cases given by the antecedent:

1. $P \land \neg Q$
2. $P$